# react-image-magnify reduce height and width

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to reduce Height and Width i am using react-image-magnify for zooming. i want to set fixed height and width for proper image zooming control.

```js
<ReactImageMagnify
    {...{
      smallImage: {
        alt: "Wristwatch by Ted Baker London",
        isFluidWidth: true,
        src: data.image,
        srcSet: data.image,
        sizes: "(max-width: 480px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 30vw, 360px"
      },
      largeImage: {
        isFluidWidth: true,
        src: data.image,
        width: 1200,
        height: 1800
      },
      enlargedImageContainerStyle: {
        zIndex: "1"
      }
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReactImageMagnify
            {...{
              smallImage: {
                className: "large",
                src: `${image}`,
                width: 380,
                height: 480,
              },
              largeImage: {
                className: "small",
                src: `${image}`,
                width: 600,
                height: 600,
              },
            }}
          />
```

In this React Image Magnify the height and width of the large image can be set automatically by setting width and height separately like the above code or verify this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-magnify/v/2.0.3